# Passing data attribute from Ajax to PHP using Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I am trying to pass a variable from function.php(ajax) to pass_userid.php. Both files are inside my plugin folder. I am attempting to pass the data attribute from function.php(ajax) to pass_userid.php but it did not send the data and received error 500.

[image]

**Plugin structure:**

-plugin folder

--function.js

--pass_userid.php

This is my function.php

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

function custom_ajax(){

    ?>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
                       
                   $('[data-source-id="13487"]').on("load", function() {
                       $('[data-source-id="13487"]').contents().find('button.button.ld-gb-gradebook-component-grade-add').click(function() {
                            var ajaxurl = "https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/wp-content/plugins/gradebook-custom/pass_userid.php";
                            var user_id = $('[data-source-id="13487"]').contents().find('.ld-gb-gradebook-component-overall-grade').attr('data-user-id');
                            alert(user_id);
                            $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: ajaxurl,
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    data: {
                                        'action' : 'call_userid',
                                        'userid' : user_id},
                                    success: function(data)
                                    {
                                       console.log("data pass success!");
                                    },
                                    error: function(errorThrown){
                                       console.log("no data pass!");
                                    }
                             });
                           
                       });
                       


                   });

                });
        </script>
    <?php

}

add_action('wp_head', 'custom_ajax');



?>
```

This is pass_userid.php:

```
<?php

function call_userid(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        $testing = $_REQUEST["userid"];
        
        console.log("Test 123");
    }
}

add_action("wp_ajax_call_userid", "call_userid");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_call_userid", "call_userid");

?>
```

Comment: console.log("Test 123"); is not php code. its javascript.

Comment: use `echo "test";`

Comment: Making the request directly to your PHP script file's URL is wrong, you need to make this request against the WP AJAX endpoint URL. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins